# DB2 for i SQL delete rows in 2 tables joined by foreign key using child value

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, delete-row

I have a parent and a child table joined by parent_id and I want to delete rows from both tables using a value in the child table

this is what I tried and it is not working

```
WITH
-- DELETE THE COSTS FIRST AND LET DB2 STORE THE IDs IN AN 'OLD TABLE'
DELETED_CHILD(ID) AS (SELECT PAYABLE_ID FROM OLD TABLE (
DELETE FROM MYLIB.MYCOST
WHERE KEY_VALUE = '1000000'
)
),
-- DELETE THE PAYABLE HEADER USING THE DELETED_LINK IDs
DELETED_PARENT(ID) AS (SELECT PAYABLE_ID FROM OLD TABLE (
DELETE FROM MYLIB.MYPAYABLE
WHERE PAYABLE_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM DELETED_CHILD) 
)
) 
(
-- SELECT IN WITH STATEMENT IS MANDATORY USELESS STATEMENT
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
);
```

The Error I get is

> Error code -199, SQL state 42601: [SQL0199] Keyword TABLE not expected. Valid tokens: ) FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT.

I want to delete all the children per value and then their parents.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which version of IBM i? _Data change tables_ may not be supported in older versions.

Comment: A _data-change-table-reference_ is allowed in DB2 for i beginning at release 6.1, but only INSERT statements may be used at least up to IBM i 7.3.

Comment: I am running on an old 7.1, what is the solution?

Comment: Guessing the FK relationship is not setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Someting like this

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE DELETED_CHILD AS ( 
SELECT * FROM MYLIB.MYCOST
WHERE KEY_VALUE = '1000000'  
) WITH DATA WITH REPLACE NOT LOGGED;

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE DELETED_PARENT AS ( 
SELECT * FROM MYLIB.MYPAYABLE
WHERE PAYABLE_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM QTEMP.DELETED_CHILD) 
) WITH DATA WITH REPLACE NOT LOGGED;

DELETE FROM MYLIB.MYCOST
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM QTEMP.DELETED_CHILD);

DELETE FROM MYLIB.MYPAYABLE
WHERE PAYABLE_ID IN (SELECT PAYABLE_ID FROM QTEMP.DELETED_PARENT ) ;

select PAYABLE_ID, 'CHILD' TYPEDELETED FROM QTEMP.DELETED_CHILD 
union all
select PAYABLE_ID, 'PARENT' TYPEDELETED FROM QTEMP.DELETED_PARENT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Foreign Key relationship has been created with "**ON DELETE CASCADE**"

```
   DELETE FROM PARENT
        WHERE PARENT_ID in (
                SELECT CHILD_ID FROM CHILD_TABLE
                 WHERE CHILD_FIELD = 'XXXXX'
```

---

**How to setup the [Referential / Foreign Key Constraint](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzatabl.htm):**

Refer to: [W3Schools Foreign Key Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE MYLIB.MYCOST
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_MYCOST
    FOREIGN KEY ( PAYABLE_ID )
    REFERENCES MYLIB.MYPAYABLE( PAYABLE_ID )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

*Referential Constaint Caveats:*

- Tables Journaled
- Parent ID must be Unique/Primary Key